# Google script to email link to sheet saved as a result of a previous script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a Google Form and it's connected to a Google Sheet.

Once the new data hits the sheet, I have a trigger set to save the file as a new file named by a specific cell (TestRange - below).

I want to send an email to the most recent email entry. The email should contain the URL to the most recently saved file.

The idea is that the user who entered the form data gets their specific copy of the sheet that I saved for them.

Here is my code:

```
function myFunction(){ 
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PQReport").activate();  
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var range = ss.getRange('PQData!C3');
    ss.setNamedRange('FileName', range);
    var TestRange = ss.getRangeByName('FileName').getValue();
    Logger.log(TestRange); 
    var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("aswwed...askdjksjdffkjdkf");
    DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).makeCopy(TestRange, destFolder); '
}
```

The file is saved as the cell value of `PQData!C3` in the `destFolder`.
The email address I want to use is the last row of `PQData!CV` (column 48).  If there was a way to save the URL of the recently saved file to column 50, then call to that column to pick up the URL in the email, that would be ideal.  
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Hello, please try to format the question according to Stackoverfolw's formatting guidlines. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: The file whose URL you want to send corresponds to the copy made in `DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).makeCopy(TestRange, destFolder);`? And your question is how to send an email containing that URL?

Comment: Daniel H - Understood and will be aware of that next time.

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

Assuming that you want to do the following:

- Retrieve the URL from the copied file made in `DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).makeCopy(TestRange, destFolder);`.
- Save this URL to the last row, column 50 of sheet `PQData`.
- Retrieve an email address from last row, column 48 of sheet `PQData`.
- Send an email to this email address, containing the URL of the file.

#### Solution:

- Use [File.getUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getUrl()) to get the URL of the file.
- Use [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow) to get the last row in your sheet.
- Use [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column) to retrieve a cell based on the row and column coordinates (no need to use A1 notation).
- Use [MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String)) to send your email, with the `URL` on the `body` parameter.

```
function myFunction(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var pqDataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("PQData");
  var range = pqDataSheet.getRange('C3');
  ss.setNamedRange('FileName', range);
  var TestRange = ss.getRangeByName('FileName').getValue();
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("aswwed...askdjksjdffkjdkf");
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).makeCopy(TestRange, destFolder);
  var url = file.getUrl();
  var lastRow = pqDataSheet.getLastRow();
  pqDataSheet.getRange(lastRow, 50).setValue(url);
  var email = pqDataSheet.getRange(lastRow, 48).getValue(); // Alternatively getRange("AV" + lastRow)
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, "MY SUBJECT", url);
}
```

#### Notes:

- `PQData!CV` does not refer to column 48, it would be `AV` instead. Please be careful with this.
- I removed mention of `PQReport` since you are not using it in your code, please add it if necessary.
- Why setting a named range and getting a value from that range instead of directly retrieving the value from `C3`?

Comment: This is really helpful and it does about 90% of what I needed it to (and thanks for cleaning up the code), no fault of yours that it is not 100%!  I didn't articulate one minor thing well in the ask.  By the last row of "PQDataAV" I actually meant that I want to search for the row that most recently had data added to it, then look to add the URL to column AV, that row.  A form is pushing new data into columns A-AU and I want to add the URL in AV after the data from the form populates.  Then I want to retrieve the email address from column 48 of that same row.

Comment: I was able to fix this using some additional code to figure out the the last row where data was added.  Really appreciate the help @lamblichus.